# org.quartz-scheduler nullify the reference of repository in the executeInternal(JobExecutionContext executionContext) why?

Tags: quartz-scheduler, spring-data-jpa, quartz-core

Its an observation and would like to share the information to know why `executeInternal()` nullify the reference of `customerRepository`? I was developing **Spring + Quartz + Spring Data JPA** example. In this example I was looking to run the multiple jobs at the same time by providing implementation of `JobDetailFactoryBean`. In `jobA.java` class I experience an issue....

**JobA.java**

```
@Service
public class JobA extends QuartzJobBean {

    private CustomerRepository customerRepository = null;

    @Autowired
    public JobA(CustomerRepository customerRepository) {
        this.customerRepository = customerRepository;
    }
    public JobA() { }

    @Override
    protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext executionContext) throws JobExecutionException {
        System.out.println("~~~~~~~ Job A is runing ~~~~~~~~");
        Trigger trigger = executionContext.getTrigger();
        System.out.println(trigger.getPreviousFireTime());
        System.out.println(trigger.getNextFireTime());
        getCustomerList();
    }

    private List<Customer> getCustomerList(){
        List<Customer> customers = customerRepository.findAll();
        for (Customer customer : customers) {
            System.out.println("------------------------------");
            System.out.println("ID : "+customer.getId());
            System.out.println("NAME : "+customer.getName());
            System.out.println("STATUS : "+customer.getStatus());
        }
        return customers;
    }
}
```

I can't use the `customerRepository` instance in the `executeInternal()` why ? If I `getCustomerList()` from public `JobA(CustomerRepository customerRepository) {` it works fine there, but if I use from `executeInternal()`, it nullify the reference of customerRepository why ?

**Spring-Quartz.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xmlns:repository="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository/spring-repository.xsd">

    <import resource="classpath:dataSourceContext.xml"/>

    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.mkyong.repository" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mkyong.*" />
    <context:annotation-config />

    <bean id="jobA" class="com.mkyong.job.JobA" />
    <bean id="jobB" class="com.mkyong.job.JobB" />
    <bean id="jobC" class="com.mkyong.job.JobC" />

    <!-- ~~~~~~~~~ Quartz Job ~~~~~~~~~~ -->
    <bean name="JobA" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean">
        <property name="jobClass" value="com.mkyong.job.JobA" />
    </bean>

    <bean name="JobB" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean">
        <property name="jobClass" value="com.mkyong.job.JobB" />
    </bean>

    <bean name="JobC" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean">
        <property name="jobClass" value="com.mkyong.job.JobC" />
    </bean>

    <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~ Cron Trigger, run every 5 seconds ~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
    <bean id="cronTriggerJobA" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerFactoryBean">
        <property name="jobDetail" ref="JobA" />
        <property name="cronExpression" value="0/5 * * * * ?" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="cronTriggerJobB" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerFactoryBean">
        <property name="jobDetail" ref="JobB" />
        <property name="cronExpression" value="0/5 * * * * ?" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="cronTriggerJobC" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerFactoryBean">
        <property name="jobDetail" ref="JobC" />
        <property name="cronExpression" value="0/5 * * * * ?" />
    </bean>

    <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  Scheduler bean Factory   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
        <property name="triggers">
            <list>
                <ref bean="cronTriggerJobA" />
                <!-- <ref bean="cronTriggerJobB" />
                <ref bean="cronTriggerJobC" /> -->
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**dataSourceContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:database.properties"/>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"/>


    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${mysql.driver.class.name}" />
        <property name="url" value="${mysql.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${mysql.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${mysql.password}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
        <property name="generateDdl" value="true"/>
        <property name="database" value="${database.vendor}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>

        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter"/>

        <!-- spring based scanning for entity classes-->
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.mkyong.*"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**App.java**

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Spring-Quartz.xml");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where are you define the `customerRepository` bean? you should define it in the xml file, or add `@Repository` annonation in the class.